# Magento 1 with Php 7.2, add to cart error if product have option

Tags: product, cart, php-7, magento-1.9.3.10

I have Magento 1.9.3.10 with the patch for PHP 7.2 applied.
If I click "add to cart" on a product that has options and no options are selected, I get this error:

```
Exception: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Select.php on line 57 in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:232
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Select.php(57): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'count(): Parame...', '/var/www/html/a...', 57, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php(533): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_Select->validateUserValue(NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php(322): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract->_prepareOptions(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php(410): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract->_prepareProduct(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(969): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract->prepareForCartAdvanced(Object(Varien_Object), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'full')
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1045): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProductAdvanced(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object), 'full')
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(268): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object))
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(235): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(686): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /var/www/html/index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exception: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object
>   that implements Countable

It is already **Fixed in 1.9.4.0**.

Comment: Do you how this is fixed by Magento 1.9.4.0? I ran a diff between Magento 1.9.3.10 including the PHP 7.2 patch and Magento 1.9.4.0, but I can't find it.

Comment: What specific custom option are you using? Please show your product settings in the admin panel.